# Custom font for LaTeX+dvips

Tags: fonts, dvips

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\special{papersize=145mm,220mm}
\textwidth=113mm \textheight=180mm
\topmargin=-14mm
\footskip=11mm
\oddsidemargin=-12.6mm
\evensidemargin=-6.4mm

\newfont{\weird}{abcr8r at 14pt}

\begin{document}
{\weird 1234567890 abcd}
\medskip
 \lipsum
\end{document}
```

The Publisher needs the pagestyle with pagenumber and headings with EuropaDemi font (and they have no own stylefile and even almost never work with LaTeX manuscripts!)

I took this font EuropeDemi.otf and after some conversions with creation afm-, tfm-, ttf- and vf- files I have created new TTFONTS folder and added it into config. Thus I have assigned this font as some new fontfamily 'abc'.

In TFM-folder there are 5 files: abcr8r, abcr8t, abcr7t, abcr6a and rabcr6a (though no difference in their usage is detected)

For texifying I need LateX->Dvips (and russian encodings)

But in *.dvi and *.ps these newfont-letters look as rasterized, with bad margins. Though the original EuropeDemi.otf in Microsoft Word, say, looks OK if I increase resolution or increase the lettersize.

1) Does anybody know the reason and ways to fix/avoid? Maybe some 'internal' ways to add this font (like packages, not the creation of these files by myself).

2) What do the numbers 6,7,8 in the tfm-files names (abcr8r, abcr8t, abcr7t, abcr6a and rabcr6a) mean? For pagenumbers I need 14pt, for title even larger

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48712/discussion-on-question-by-torcli-custom-font-for-latexdvips).

Answer (score 1):

If XeLaTeX is an option, then you can use the font easily by installing it for your OS and using `fontspec`. This has the advantage of allowing you to use `\special`s which you cannot use with pdfLaTeX, because XeLaTeX processes `.tex` in a multi-stage process, similar to the process of using LaTeX followed by post-compilation conversion to PDF.

I don't have your font, but here's an example with one I do have. Note that we need to specify a non-default driver for `geometry` in order to allow the `\special`s. The default is `xetex` but your comments suggest that this may be less suitable for your code and that you probably want to specify an alternative. I've used `geometry` because this is recommended over setting layout dimensions manually and will automatically ensure that appropriate options are passed through to the back-end driver.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{driver=dvipdfm,,papersize={145mm,220mm},textheight=180mm,footskip=11mm,inner=12.8mm,outer=19mm,verbose}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myweirdfont{Neris Light}
\DeclareRobustCommand\weird{\fontsize{14pt}{18pt}\myweirdfont}

\begin{document}
{\weird 1234567890 abcd\par}
\medskip
 \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: weird font and regular font]

I don't have any Cyrillic to test, but `polyglossia` can be used or `babel` will also work. `fontspec` can switch to the Cyrillic script when required. See `fontspec`'s manual and, if applicable, `polyglossia`'s.

Note that this solution requires your `.tex` file to be UTF-8 encoded. If you have any trouble with standard TeX ligatures such as `--`, `---` etc., you may have an older version of `fontspec`. In that case just add

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
```

which is now default but did not used to be.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dvips cannot handle ttf fonts, only pk and Type1 (pfb) fonts; so, in the absence of a sensible pfb, it falls back to Metafont or, in your case, `ttf2pk` to produce and include raster fonts.
2. You need to read the [fontname documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontname) which explains the "standard" naming scheme for fonts constrained by the 8.3 format of lore (DOS and VAX, for instance). In this case, 8r is 8bit raw; 8t is 8bit Cork TeX encoding; 7t is 7bit Old TeX encoding; 6a is for the T2A Cyrillic encodings. All fonts for 8bit TeXes need an encoding identifier to use the appropriate alphabets/scripts.

So, if you want to go the old [La]TeX+dvips way, you'll need:

1. `sourcefontname.pfb` and `sourcefontname.afm` files. You could get these files by processing your font with, say, FontForge.
2. Make `tfm` files for your font with the appropriate encodings following the instructions given for LY1 on [TUG](https://www.tug.org/yandy/maketfm.htm), for instance:

```
afm2tfm [sourcefontname] -T T2A.enc -v [targetfontname].vpl >> [targetfontname].map
pltotf [targetfontname].vpl
```

You should get a `targetfontname.tfm` and a `targetfontname.map` files, which you should install; and a temporary `targetfontname.vpl` which you may discard.

Alternatively, you may use the `afm2pl` tool.

```
afm2pl -p T2A.enc [sourcefontname] [targetfontname]
pltotf [targetfontname]
```

3. Put the `pfb` file in `/fonts/type1/foundry"`, the `tfm` file in `/fonts/tfm/foundry`, and the `map` in the `/fonts/map/dvips` directories, and execute `updmap --add targetfontname.map` on your system.
4. Load the [targetfontname] in your source code and execute LaTeX and dvips as usual. This procedure also sets up your font for pdflatex.

If you decide to go this way, I encourage you to follow the guidelines given in [fontname](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontname) to put names to your fonts. It's just a matter of standardization.

Syntax for the font utilities may vary if you use a non-TeXLive based implementation, like MikTeX's. Check your documentation for details.